# Restarting Remote computer in amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, restart

I want to restart one of my servers on the amazon AWS.
I started to write an app that does this.
but practically struck when attempting to connect to the remote server.

try
{
ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown.exe", "-r /m\IP Address");
                            Process.Start(startinfo);
}

this is working to restart the local computer it is running on.

am i missing some parameters to pass along with IPAddress here?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i was trying to do is to issue a Reboot-Instance command with actually creating an EC2 instance object created.

Did that correctly and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this...

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/

Basically, from a remote system issue an ec2-reboot-instances command to restart your instance.